# Infinitely nested radicals under fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

Good morning everyone, I encountered a calculation procedure (structural dimensioning) that proceeds by trial and error in a recursive manner, which converges to a value. From various steps I arrived at the following nested infinite radical which unfortunately I cannot resolve further with my skills.

$$x_{1} = \frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{a}}$$
$$x_{2} = \frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{x_{1}}}=\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{a}}}}$$
$$x_{3} = \frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{x_{2}}}=\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{x_{1}}}}}=\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{\frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{a}}}}}}$$
$$...$$
$$ k, a \in \Re \qquad k > 0 \qquad a >0$$

What I would like to know is:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{x_n} = ? $$

Since I don't need an exact result, which may be too complicated to quantify, I would also like a formula with an approximation of $$ \pm 1‰$$

Thank you

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I think you don't want $L$ in the numerator.

Comment: The limit (IF it exists) has to be such that applying the recursion to it would return the limit.  SO $L = \frac {a}{1+k\sqrt L}$ and you just have to solve for $L$.  *BUT* you have to first prove that a limit exists, or in other words that $x_i$ converge.  That can be the hard part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relation is $x_{n+1} = \frac{a}{1+k \sqrt{x_n}}$

If we assume a fixed point $L$ exists, it will satisfy $L = \frac{a}{1+k \sqrt L}$:$$
\begin{align}
L+kL\sqrt{L} &= a\\
k (\sqrt L)^3 + (\sqrt L)^2 -a & = 0
\end{align}
$$

This is a cubic in terms of $\sqrt L$. This is a special case of cubic (no linear term). Because the constant term is negative, this will have exactly one positive root. Since we're solving for $\sqrt L > 0$, that's the solution we want. I had Mathematica evaluate it for me (you can read up on the cubic formula if you're interested); then I simplified it a bit by hand:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt L &= \frac{\sqrt[3]{27 a k^2+\sqrt{\left(2-27 a k^2\right)^2-4}-2}}{3 \sqrt[3]{2} k}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3 k \sqrt[3]{27 a k^2+\sqrt{\left(2-27 a k^2\right)^2-4}-2}}-\frac{1}{3 k} \\
A &= ak^2 > 0 \\
\sqrt L &= \frac{1}{3k} \left( \frac{\sqrt[3]{27A+\sqrt{\left(2-27 A\right)^2-4}-2}}{\sqrt[3]{2} }+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{27 A+\sqrt{\left(2-27 A\right)^2-4}-2}}-1 \right) \\
B &= 27A-2 = 27 ak^2 - 2 \\
\sqrt L &= \frac{1}{3k} \left( \frac{\sqrt[3]{B+\sqrt{B^2-4}}}{\sqrt[3]{2} }+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{B+\sqrt{B^2-4}}}-1 \right)
\end{align}
$$
If $|B|<2$, $B^2-4<0$ so $\sqrt{B^2-4}$ doesn't work/produces a complex result. That can happen if $27 ak^2 < 4$. There's still a positive root to the equation in that case, but this formula Mathematica produced is not directly applicable in that case. You can read more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula)

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I solved it!